# show hide using animate.css bounce

Tags: jquery, animate.css

This works

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop();
if (scrollPosition > 50) {
  $('.top-nav').show();
} else {
  $('.top-nav').hide();
}});
```

This works only once (what happens after bounce out? since i cannot get the element bounce back again)

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop();
if (scrollPosition > 50) {
    $('.top-nav').css('visibility', 'visible').addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
} else {
    $('.top-nav').addClass('animated bounceOutLeft');
}
});
```

Comment: Any reason you are not reversing the visibility on else? I would assume you want to remove the class 'bounceInLeft' on else as well and remove the class 'bounceOutLeft' on if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is executing as follows:

1. `scrollPosition` is at the Top
2. When `scrollPosition` goes over 50 you are adding the classes `animated` and `bounceInLeft` to the `.top-nav` element
3. If the `scrollPosition` remains over 50 nothing happens
4. When the `scrollPosition` goes below 50, for the first time, you are not removing the `bounceInLeft` class instead you are adding `bounceOutLeft`. Only in this occurrence, when adding `bounceOutLeft` it will work, however:
5. When the scrollPosition goes below or over 50, both classes `bounceInLeft` and `bounceOutLeft` are already assigned to the `.top-nav` element => **Nothing happens.**

The above is only one possible scenario, but the bottom line is still the same, you are adding animation classes and not **toggling** them.

*Same applies to the visibility. Well, almost...*

Comment: yep you were totally right just needed to remove the original class. Thank you so much for the help!